# composer require package_name requested for api/v3 not api/v4 on gitlab

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab

When I want to require a package **with composer** it will return an error message:

composer require Bugloos/file-manager-bundle:1.0.6

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.                                                                                   
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                          
  The "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/bugloos%2Flogin%2Dbundle" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 410 Gone)
```

**But if I click on the link with v4 gitlab will return the correct response, I don't know how to tell gitlab response me with v4 version?**

```
"repositories": [
{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "git@gitlab.com:bugloos/login-bundle.git"
},
```

...

```
"require": {
   "Bugloos/LoginBundle": "^1.0", ...
```

...

[image]

Comment: Where is this url present? In `composer.lock`? In `composer.json` for `repositories`?

Comment: @GrenierJ I have updated the question, that is in the terminal when composer throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution is:**

Update the verison of composer, but **with phar** not package manager!

I have updated the composer version by removing it and installing the latest version again, and also because I installed the composer via ubuntu package manager it didn't support this command:

```
composer self-update > only works if you installed it with phar
```

**But if you didn't installed it with phar** you have to remove it and install it again from [official website](https://getcomposer.org/download/) like this:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'c5b9b6d368201a9db6f74e2611495f369991b72d9c8cbd3ffbc63edff210eb73d46ffbfce88669ad33695ef77dc76976') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Comment: You should always install composer from it website [composer download](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Answer (score 2):

This [was fixed](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/6832eacb0161ecec4666a7d2456a474e3f8e903d) in Composer over two years ago. You need to update your composer:

```
composer self-update
```

or with sudo if composer is installed globally:

```
sudo -H composer self-update
```